# My javascript code is crashing when I put a random number generator/guesser into a function. Why does it crash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have build a random number generator used to guess numbers. I have limited this number guesser not to ask the same number twice and this works outside of the function. as soon as I put the number generator/guesser into a function the window crashes every few attempts. I believe this has to do with the number generating on an infinite loop. Can anyone see what the issue is?

Edit: for those who like to see the HTML as well. I have two simple inputs before the JS:

```
<body>

    <p>Think of a number!</p>

    <select name="fingers" id="mynumber">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>

    <button id="startguess">Start guessing my number!</button>
```

Here are the global variables:

```
        var guessed = [""];

        var guess = "";
```

Here is the function:

```
        function doaguess(correctanswer) {

            guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

            var n = "";

            n = guessed.includes(guess);

            if (n == true) {

                guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

            } else {

                if (guess == correctanswer) {

                    return (true);

                } else {

                    return (false);

                }

            }

        }
```

And the rest of the script is this:

```
        document.getElementById("startguess").onclick = function() {

            var mynumber = document.getElementById("mynumber").value;

            var gotit = false;

            var numberofguesses = 1;

            while (gotit == false) {

                if (doaguess(mynumber) == true) {

                    gotit = true;

                    alert("Got it! It was a " + mynumber + ". It took me " + numberofguesses + " guesses.");

                } else {

                    numberofguesses++;
                    guessed.push(guess);

                }

            }

        }
```

Everything worked fine until I moved the generator into the function `doaguess()`. I have tried moving the variables into global from local to change the scope and this made the code work but it now crashes. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: for those who like to see the HTML as well. I have two simple inputs before the JS:

Comment: can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @JaydipJadhav No, there does not need a break, the op is setting got it to true and that will end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you guess the number after `(n == true)` you are not returning anything, and the guess could be a repetead one, that should be into a loop also searching for a new guess. When you guess the number in that case, then the result is not true and the correct answer is added in the `guessed` array causing the infinite loop.

Fix:

```
n = guessed.includes(guess);


while (n == true) {

    guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    n = guessed.includes(guess);    
}

if (guess == correctanswer) {

       return (true);

   } else {

       return (false);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking before. I haven't had the same problem without using the `makeaguess()` function but I have changed the other file this way and it works. However this still crashes with the `makeaguess()` function format

Answer (score 0):

Its this line `guessed.push(guess);` should be `guessed.push(mynumber);`

Here is it working:

```js
var guessed = [""];
var guess = "";

function doaguess(correctanswer) {
  guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var n = guessed.includes(guess);

  if (n === true) {
    guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  } else {
    return guess == correctanswer;
  }
}


document.getElementById("startguess").onclick = function() {
  var mynumber = document.getElementById("mynumber").value;
  var gotit = false;
  var numberofguesses = 1;

  while (!gotit) {
    if (doaguess(mynumber)) {
      gotit = true;
      alert("Got it! It was a " + mynumber + ". It took me " + numberofguesses + " guesses.");
    } else {
      numberofguesses++;
      guessed.push(mynumber);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="startguess">Guess</button>
<input id="mynumber" type="number"></input>
```

Comment: mynumber is the number you choose that the computer then has to guess. it wouldnt make sense to push this number to the array

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. The variables are not resetting every time I try to offer a number so it appears not to work if I try multiple times without reloading the page because the numbers are stored instead of resetting at each new "play". To resolve this I need to reset the variables and arrays `guess` and `guessed` every time the `onclick` is pressed. Like this:

```
        document.getElementById("startguess").onclick = function() {

            guessed = [""];

            guess = "";

            var mynumber = document.getElementById("mynumber").value;

            var gotit = false;

            var numberofguesses = 1;

            while (gotit == false) {

                if (doaguess(mynumber) == true) {

                    gotit = true;

                    alert("Got it! It was a " + mynumber + ". It took me " + numberofguesses + " guesses.");

                } else {

                    numberofguesses++;
                    guessed.push(guess);

                }

            }

        }
```